# How to use .on() using querySelector in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-selectors

I want to rewrite the following jquery code using querySelector method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('#woocommerce-product-data').on('woocommerce_variations_loaded', function() {
        $(this).find('.woocommerce_variation').each(function() {

       });
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const EL_wc_pdata = document.querySelector("#woocommerce-product-data");
EL_wcp_data.addEventListener("woocommerce_variations_loaded", function() {
  const ELs_wc_var = EL_wc_pdata.querySelectorAll(".woocommerce_variation");
  ELs_wc_var.forEach(el => {
    // el.
  });
});
```